# Sencha Touch/Phonegap Javascript files not loading on iPad but load in iPad Simulator

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch 1.1/Phonegap 1.3 application that works correctly on the iPad Simulator but has some issues on an iPad device.

The problems occur with a custom UI control I've named `listfield` that has code in `/lib/ListField/ListField.js`.

My `index.html` files has the following script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ListField/Ext.form.Listfield.js"></script>
```

I can't see any problems with it and it works in webkit browsers on my Windows PC and the iPad simulator on the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the filename in the script tag doesn't exactly match the actual filename.

It seems that the script tags are case-sensitive when running on an actual iPad.  I changed the script tag to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ListField/Ext.form.ListField.js"></script>
```

and the problem was resolved.